# How can I filter and highlight a date range within multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use a very lengthy excel spreadsheet which includes columns A thru K and has several hundred numbered rows. Three of the rows contain multiple dates. Please see example.

How can I select a filter to "highlight" the rows/columns when I'm trying to look for a specific date range? Currently I'm having to eyeball the date when I scroll and I know there's got to be a better way.  I appreciate your response in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to filter out highlight? Are you looking for values from all columns within the date range, or do you want to do something else? Please EDIT your question to clarify these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a filter? Select all the data including the headers, click the `Data` tab, then `Filter`.

[image]

You can then filter each column to display exactly what you need to work with:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying to filter out certain dates from three different columns that are very lengthy. For example, if a row has three different dates: Column A has a date of 02/11/2016, Column B has 02/04/2016 and Column C has 02/15/2016. If I want to look for a specific date range across multiple rows, like 02/01/2016 thru 02/05/2016.  from what you've listed above is that the way I could highlight the dates within my range (02/01/2016 thru 02/05/2016) throughout the entire spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kimaa68 If I understand correctly, you can just uncheck the dates you don't wish to display for each column (uncheck `select all` and only check the ones you want), only leaving the rows that match behind? Alternatively, you can set up conditional formatting if you simply want to highlight the rows, giving a date comparison as a condition.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much. I appreciate your response.